# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Config' not found

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

I have build a custom MVC Framework.
Local its working fine, when I try to get it working on a live shared hosting server I will get this error:

**Error Message in Browser:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Config' not found in /www/htdocs/user/project/public/index.php:19 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /www/htdocs/user/project/public/index.php on line 19

**Composer.json file:**

```
{
  "require": {
    "filp/whoops": "^2.3",
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Core\\": "core/",
      "App\\": "app/"
    }
  }
}
```

**My Folder & File structure:** (The whole project is inside the folder: "project")

[image]

**Index.php File**

```
    <?php

/**
 * Front controller
 */

use App\Config;

/**
 * Composer autoloading
 */

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

/**
 * Whoops Error and Exception handling
 */

if (Config::SHOW_ERRORS == true){
    $whoops = new \Whoops\Run;
    $whoops->pushHandler(new \Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler);
    $whoops->register();
}

/**
 * Sessions
 */

session_start();

/**
 * Routing
 */

$router = new Core\Router();

// Add the routes
$router->add('', ['controller' => 'Home', 'action' => 'index']);
```

**Config.php file:**

```
<?php

/**
 * Application configuration
 */

namespace App;

class Config {

    /**
     * Database host
     * @var string
     */

    const DB_HOST = 'localhost';

    /**
     * Mail SMTP Port
     * @var int
     */

    const SMTP_PORT = '2525';
}
```

**My method to deploy to the server:**

1. ZIP the local files & Export mysql database
2. upload zip to server -> unzip it
3. upload db to phpmyadmin
4. Change database credentials in Config File
5. run `composer install` (I also tried: `composer install --no-dev`)
6. Done

I have repeated this procedure for several times now but its still not working

Comment: try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Are both systems running the same OS? (`app/` vs `App/`)

Comment: in index.php are you loading the composer autoload file?

Comment: composer dump-autoload brings no change

I have added the index.php to the post, please check it out

Comment: You should use autoload before use App/Config.

Comment: I tried it but still no change

Comment: What error you get when you set "require autoload..." before "use App\Config;" ?

Comment: I will get exactly the same error

Comment: Warning: require(/www/htdocs/user/project/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open 
    stream: No such file or directory in /www/htdocs/user/pproject/public/index.php on 
    line 7

    Warning: require(/www/htdocs/user/project/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open 
    stream: No such file or directory in /www/htdocs/user/project/public/index.php on 
    line 7

    Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 
    '/www/htdocs/user/project/../vendor/autoload.php' 
    (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:..') in /www/htdocs/user/project/public/index.php 
    on line 7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188823/discussion-between-leon-and-medskill).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was caused by using a Symbolic Link in Windows.
I am using WAMP and PHP framework CodeIgniter (version 4.2.1). Some versions of CodeIgniter have issues with this.

Possible cause:

I think the cause is the use of the PHP function file_exists. The function returns a FALSE in some cases when the path contains a symbolic link with certain characters.
Or the problem is in sanitizing the filename.

Possible solutions:

1. Ask the developers of CodeIgniter to fix this problem. I can't wait for that now.
2. Override the functions of the framework in which the problem occurs. Takes me too much time to figure this out.
3. Use an older version of CodeIgniter that does not have the issue. This, of course, has other drawbacks.
4. Do not use a symbolic link. Duh!
5. Make sure the symbolic link does not contain any 'special' characters.

Solution 5 was the easiest for me. I had to remove the brackets () in my symbolic link name and that solved the problem.

Maybe this helps someone else.

Comment: Thanks for posting your (elaborated) solution/answer. For community projects like Codeigniter, 1. offers a benefit _despite_ not having the time to wait for upstream fixes: Reporting the issue (and your work-around). It depends from project to project (and the reporting person naturally) how well a "bug report" is recieved, but in my experience even when no clear solution/code is already at hand, the sheer report can make a difference. Just saying. (especially with portability issues  feedback most often is welcome esp. if there is a clear report and also a practical way out reported)

Comment: @hakre: thanks for your comment. I will report it to the CodeIgniter devs.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried to do the same thing and it seems work, check this:

/index.php

```
<?php

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php'; // It must be called first

use App\Config;

echo Config::get('test');
// Result: test
```

/App/Config.php

```
namespace App;

class Config 
{
    public function get($str)
    {   
        return $str;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is case sensitivity problem - your autoloading rules uses `app` as directory name, but this is actually `App`. This may work on case insensitive filesystems (Windows) but it will not work on case sensitive filesystems (Linux). You should fix your autoloading rules to:

```
{
  "require": {
    "filp/whoops": "^2.3",
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Core\\": "Core/",
      "App\\": "App/"
    }
  }
}
```